# Closing Parent Window containing frames

Tags: javascript, window

I have an html page named **abc.html** containing 2 horizontal frames. Frame 2 contains some php and javascript code. The page inside frame 2 is designed in such a way that it will perform some tasks and then it opens a new tab. After opening a new tab my work shift to that page and the current page "abc.html" is no more needed. So I need to close it. Need some help to close it after opening a new tab. I have tried **window.close()** and **close();**. non of them done the job.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to close a window with javascript that was not previously created through javascript.